# Is it possible to use "unique together" in Laravel, similarly to Django?

Tags: django, laravel

So in Django you can do this: `unique_together = ('name', 'username',)` so if you try to register people like this:

1. name: John, username: blabla <---- this gets registered
2. name: John, username: haha   <---- this gets registered
3. name: John, username: blabla <---- this won't get registered because the combination of John and blabla already exists.

Is the something similar is Laravel I could use?

The main goal is to check if the name with the username exists together, if it does, throw back a validation error, otherwise register the record to the database.

edit #1: if I can get something like "unique together" in laravel, is it possible to modify the validation method based on a hidden field in the form?

For example I want the user to write their name and email and submit it, and have a checkbox. The checkbox would enable/disable the 'unique' check of the name, so like if I do this:

name: John Doe Corp. email: whatever, checkbox: Ticked

then it would check the 'name' column for duplicates.
Otherwise:

name: Jane Doe. email: whatever, checkbox: Not Ticked

then it would not check the name column for duplicates, allowing the record to be saved into the database.

Comment: Read here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: oh, the `'email' => 'unique:users,email_address'` would mean the unique together part? I thought that's like the [table],[column], so in this example in the users table the email_address column.

Comment: its table name and column name

Comment: Consider you want to `username` field to be unique based on two fields so the validation rule will be 

     'username' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function($query)use($username,$name){
                    $query->where('username',$username)->where('name',$name);
                })

Comment: Wow, that seems unnecessarily complicated... Okay, I'll give it a try in the next few days and drop a reply! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it would be in Django :). But there is unique together in Laravel migration

```
$table->unique(['code', 'organization_id']);
```

`code` and `organization_id` is column in migration I mean in table .